# Mailto not working with custom .desktop file

Tags: .desktop

My problem is that mailto links do not seem to work properly. I'm using Sylpheed, but that's not specific to the problem. I created a file at `/usr/share/applications/sylpheed-compose.desktop` so that mailto links open the proper window within sylpheed, but none of the information from the mailto url seems to matter because the compose window is always empty.

I've ensured that the line `x-scheme-handler/mailto=sylpheed-compose.desktop` is in my `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file.

Here is the content of `/usr/share/applications/sylpheed-compose.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sylpheed
Comment=E-Mail client
Exec=sylpheed --compose
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can get the information from the mailto url to fill in the compose window like it's supposed to?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution and figured I'd post it in case anybody else has the same problem. The problem was that the Exec line in the desktop file wasn't being passed the mailto url (which is `%u` inside of the .desktop file). The solution was to change the Exec line to the following:

```
Exec=sylpheed --compose %u
```